# Is it possible to get the string displayed in the URL bar using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I realize that window.location.href sometimes returns something other than the string displayed in the URL bar. Is there any way to get the string displayed in the URL bar in Javascript?

When I visit www.google.com using this user script, document.location.href is not always "www.google.com" as expected.

Comment: Heya. Just wanted to let you know, you should probably look at your edit suggestion history, if you haven't already. There are quite a number of rejected edits in there.

Comment: @Telthien How can I view a list of all edits that I've suggested, then?

Comment: Under [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/users/975097/anderson-green?tab=activity) of your profile page, there is an option called "suggestions" seen [here](http://prntscr.com/13knrw) under Activity.

Answer (score 0):

`location` has many properties which should allow you to get the part you want. Have a look at its [documentation *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location#Properties).

Chrome, by default, hides the protocol of the URI (see also @Andy E's comment).

Comment: Newer operas hide the protocol *and* the query string until you click the address bar.